# Scalar and vectorial sensitivities

Tags: sensitivities

In a recent discussion about the implementation of the calculation of derivative sensitivities, the notion 'scalar' and 'vectorial sensitivities' were used. I am not familiar with this notion and could not find any information about it. Apparently, 'Theta' is a scalar one.

Can someone shed some light on it?

Comment: Consider sensitivities with respect to an interest rate term structure.